# fetch the 1st row from the table for an employee with highest salary

Tags: sql, oracle

I am searching for a query to find the details of highest paid employee in the entire organization. I am using oracle DB.

Queries which I tried are:

```
select * from EMP order by SAL desc FETCH FIRST 1ROW ONLY;
```

> ERROR: SQL command not properly ended

```
select * from EMP order by SAL desc where rownum = 1;
```

> ERROR: SQL command not properly ended

```
select * from EMP order by SAL desc LIMIT 0 , 1;
```

> ERROR: SQL command not properly ended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * FROM emp ORDER BY sal DESC)
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

---

Please note that if rows have identifical salaries, `ROWNUMBER` will rank them randomly. To handle ties, you could use `RANK()` instead  (or maybe `DENSE_RANK()`, depending on your needs):

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        e.*,
        RANK() OVER(ORDER BY sal DESC) rn
    FROM emp
)
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: ok.. the first highest is 5000rs. so if I give rownum=1 after desc then it works. But in order to find the 2nd highest where row number 2 and 3 both are 3000 after desc, then how can I modify my query?

Comment: @beyou: `ROWNUMBER` orders tied records randomly. I updated my answer with a solution that uses `RANK()` instead, which properly handle ties.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with all three statements.

Try this:

```
select * from EMP order by SAL desc FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY;
```

or use an analytical function `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT T.* FROM
    (SELECT
            T.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SAL DESC NULLS LAST) RN
        FROM EMP) T
WHERE RN = 1
```

Cheers!!